# Need help figuring out how I should design my reinforcement learning environment

Tags: reinforcement-learning, stable-baselines

So I recently had a dumb idea to basically use RL for procedural generation. I want to start with terrain generation, but as a newcomer to RL and someone who can't quite put into words what makes a terrain heightmap "good", I'm having a hard time figuring out what actions and reward function to make for this. I assumed that having the actions be moving a "cursor" in a specific direction on the heightmap, and raising or lowering the tile that cursor points to, while having the reward function grade the AI based on whether there's too much or too little land, and whether there's adjacent land tiles, would be a good idea.

However, when I tested this in Stable Baselines 3, I got this.

[image]

Clearly I'm doing something wrong here. What is it?

Comment: I am so stupid. I just found out that the vertical lines are because the heightmap has to be an ndarray by default and not a standard two dimensional python array.